# Display rows fetched dynamically,when the filters are applied to a report in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there are any way where-in we can display the number of records that are fetched, when a query is been generated?
It should also be dynamic such that, the row count should change as filters are applied to the report.

Comment: Is there anything here that would be sufficient for what you're chasing? http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/12/count-number-of-rows-returned-in-apex.html

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried the steps but could not suffice the requirement. Would need to showcase the user the rowcount which the Interactive report fetches. Though we filter the data via in-built filters from the action Button, the data count should get refreshed :|

Comment: Tried the APEX pagination, and it worked.